# How to change owner of several files in Amazon S3?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

How to change owner of a file in Amazon S3? I'd like to do this to all files in one go.

Couldn't find any relevant material on this online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also try [Bucket Explorer](http://www.bucketexplorer.com/be-download.html), If you do not want to perform it manually, see [Copy Between two Accounts](http://www.bucketexplorer.com/documentation/amazon-s3--how-to-copy-files-and-bucket.html).

**Disclosure**: I work for Bucket Explorer.

Comment: I need to do this in batch. Not per single file. Will take too long if I have to do it for every file one by one

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change owner of the file then first you have to share that file to new owner with full control. then from second owners account you will create new file by copy operation and update new owner acl. it will change the owner of the file.

Else to being a owner of the file you can not handover ownership to other.